A group of invertible elements in fields
Let $k \subset K \subset L$ be finite purely inseparable extensions of characteristic $p >0$. Assume $k$ is separably closed and $K^p \supset \{ x \in L \; | \; x^p \in k \} = L \cap k^{1/p}$. I am interested in knowing whether the group $$ \frac{(k K^p)^\ast \cap (k^\ast L^\ast)}{k^\ast {K^p}^\ast} $$ is trivial ($kK^p$ is the subextension of $L$ generated by  and $K^p$).
If $k \subset K^p$ or $K^p \subset k$ it is obviously trivial.
Also, if $k$ and $L^p$ are linearly independent over $k^p$, then we have $(kK^p) \cap L^p = K^p$, so the group above is trivial. (See $p$-powers in a purely inseparable extension .)
I tried to use particular bases of purely inseparable extensions like $p$-bases but I don't see how to use them cleverly. So if you have ideas or references to study purely inseparable extensions, you're welcome !
